# Can't retrieve data from Firestore in onCreate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Activity with ImageView, and it clickable. When I click on the ImageView, a dialog appears with a choice of 3 items. When I select the 3 position in the dialog, I call TimePicker, in which I specify the time and it is displayed in the TextView. All the values that must be filled in the database work properly, they update and change as I need them.

The problem is that after selecting the time in TimePicker, it correctly displayed in TextView and the required number is entered in the database, but when I restart the application, I need the same number to be displayed again in TextView - but this doesn't happen. The value in the FireStore - changed, but in TextView when restarting - no.

Code of it:

```
public class ZoneOne extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageView mSceneOne, mSceneTwo;
private TextView mTextOne, mTextTwo;

public static final String KEY_SCENE_ONE = "scene_one";
public static final String KEY_SCENE_TWO = "scene_two";

public static final String KEY_TIME_ONE = "time_one";
public static final String KEY_TIME_TWO = "time_two";


private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private DocumentReference tables = db.collection("New Collection").document("New Document");
private ArrayList mSelectedItems;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private TimePickerDialog time;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zone_one);

    mSceneOne = findViewById(R.id.scene_one);
    mSceneTwo = findViewById(R.id.scene_two);

    mTextOne = findViewById(R.id.time_scene_one);
    mTextTwo = findViewById(R.id.time_scene_two);

    mTextOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSceneOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSceneTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

    tables.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String scene_one = documentSnapshot.getString("scene_one");
                        String one = documentSnapshot.getString("time_one");
                        switch (scene_one) {
                            case "0":
                                mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_green);
                                break;
                            case "1":
                                mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_red);
                                break;
                            default:
                                mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_grey);
                                mTextOne.setText(one);
                                mTextOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                        }
                        String seat_two = documentSnapshot.getString("seat_two");
                        String time_for_two = documentSnapshot.getString("time_two");
                        switch (seat_two) {
                            case "0":
                                mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_green);
                                break;
                            case "1":
                                mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_red);
                                break;
                            default:
                                mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_grey);
                                mTextTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mTextOne.setText(time_for_two);
                                break;
                        }

                    } else {

                        Map<String, Object> allData = new HashMap<>();
                        allData.put(KEY_SCENE_ONE, "0");
                        allData.put(KEY_SCENE_TWO, "0");

                        allData.put(KEY_TIME_ONE, "");
                        allData.put(KEY_TIME_TWO, "");

                        tables.set(allData);
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}

private void createDialog(int state_one, int state_two, int state_three, String key, ImageView view, TextView time, String time_key) {
    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final int finalState_one = state_one;
    final int finalState_two = state_two;
    final int finalState_three = state_three;
    final String KEY = key;
    final ImageView V = view;
    final TextView Time = time;
    final String TIME = time_key;

    final Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();

    builder.setTitle("Please choose!")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.tables, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which) {
                                case 0:
                                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    break;
                            }


                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if (mSelectedItems.contains(0)){

                        V.setImageResource(finalState_one);
                        note.put(KEY, "0");
                        tables.update(note);
                        Time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }else if (mSelectedItems.contains(1)){

                        V.setImageResource(finalState_two);
                        note.put(KEY, "1");
                        tables.update(note);
                        Time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }else if (mSelectedItems.contains(2)){

                        V.setImageResource(finalState_three);
                        note.put(KEY, "2");
                        tables.update(note);
                        Time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        showTimePicker(Time, TIME);
                    }



                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            }).create();

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

private void showTimePicker(TextView view, String key_time) {

    final TextView V = view;
    final String KEY_TIME = key_time;

    final Map<String, Object> note_time = new HashMap<>();

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    time = new TimePickerDialog(ZoneOne.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            V.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
            String time = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            note_time.put(KEY_TIME, time);
            tables.update(note_time);

        }
    }, hour, minute, true );
    time.show();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.table_one:
            createDialog(R.drawable.one_green, R.drawable.one_red, R.drawable.one_grey, KEY_SCENE_ONE, mSceneOne, mTextOne, KEY_TIME_ONE);
            break;
        case R.id.table_two:
            createDialog(R.drawable.two_green, R.drawable.two_red, R.drawable.two_grey, KEY_SCENE_TWO, mSceneTwo, mTextTwo, KEY_TIME_TWO);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Structure of database
[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293213/cant-retrieve-data-from-firestore-in-oncreate). This can result in an automatic question ban.

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated!

Comment: @AndréKool Oh, I think I don't correctly understand, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a switch statement that looks like yours:

```
switch (scene_one) {
    case "0":
        mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_green);
        break;
    case "1":
        mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_red);
        break;
    default:
        mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_grey);
        mTextOne.setText(one);
        mTextOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
}
```

It means that you are setting the String `one` to the `TExtView` only in a particular case, which is when `scene_one` is **not** `0` or `1`. As I see in your database, your `scene_one` property holds the value of `0`, this means that the `default case` will never be reached. If you want to set the `TextView`, no matter which case is, then you need to copy those lines of code in every case, `case "0"` and `case "1"`.

Comment: Ok @Alex Mamo, I understood you. I try to replace this string everywhere, try to use all variants of logic, but the problem isn't in this.  I launch app - set time in `TimePicker` - it appear in `TextView` - than I exit from app and launch again. And when I relaunch app, in `Oncreate` I try to showing that time, that was in `TextView`, and now in `Firestore`, but `TextView` is empty. When I choose time again, it's all good, time update - all works. But after relaunch again my `TextView` is empty.

Comment: I understand you but the problem still remains is in your switch statement. Try to give `scene_one` the value of three in your database, does it work now?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo, but I didn't clearly understand what was mistake in my logic. The Time must appear, only when my `case = 2`, not `0` or `1`. And I wrote this, that time must be set on `TextView` and be Visible, only when `case` isn't equal to `0` or `1`. All work like you say, but can you explain that?

Comment: This is how a switch statements works. And you should everytime check all the values that you are using for your cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
    tables.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            String scene_one =  documentSnapshot.getString("scene_one");
                            String one = documentSnapshot.getString("time_one");

                            mTextOne.setText(one);
                            mTextOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//Try to set the text here above switch and see if it works
                            switch (scene_one) {
                                case "0":
                                    mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_green);
                                    break;
                                case "1":
                                    mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_red);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    mTableOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_grey);

                                    break;
                            }
                            String seat_two = documentSnapshot.getString("seat_two");
                            String time_for_two = documentSnapshot.getString("time_two");
                            switch (seat_two) {
                                case "0":
                                    mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_green);
                                    break;
                                case "1":
                                    mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_red);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    mTableTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_grey);
                                    mTextTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    mTextOne.setText(time_for_two);
                                    break;
                            }

                        } else {

                            Map<String, Object> allData = new HashMap<>();
                            allData.put(KEY_SCENE_ONE, "0");
                            allData.put(KEY_SCENE_TWO, "0");

                            allData.put(KEY_TIME_ONE, "");
                            allData.put(KEY_TIME_TWO, "");

                            tables.set(allData);
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
```